# KNN Mahalanobis error - size of V does not match - Python

Tags: python, knn, mahalanobis

I am trying to implement a KNN model, using Mahalanobis as the distance metric, however when I execute the code I am getting an error:

> Value Error: "size of V does not match

where V is the covariance matrix of features.

Relevant parts of my code below:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=10,stratify=y)

knn2=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=20, metric='mahalanobis', metric_params={'V': np.cov(X_train)})

knn2.fit(X_train,y_train) # this is the line that causes the error.
```

I have looked at the repo on github for sklearn's distance [metric code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/_dist_metrics.pyx) (from line 628 is Mahalanobis), and can see the error arises from the following:

```
cdef inline DTYPE_t rdist(self, DTYPE_t* x1, DTYPE_t* x2,
                              ITYPE_t size) nogil except -1:
        if size != self.size:
            with gil:
                raise ValueError('Mahalanobis dist: size of V does not match')
```

I've worked out what `self.size` is in my case, but can't work out what `size` is.

Could anyone help with this error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get the answer to this?

Comment: @TomSmith Afraid not!

Comment: Answered below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the argument rowvar=False to np.cov and it should work. Your knn constructor should look like this:

```
knn2=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=20, metric='mahalanobis', metric_params={'V': np.cov(X_train, rowvar=False)})
```

Answer (score -2):

See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11807). I think it is asking for covariance between features instead of samples.

Comment: When you answer here, typically it is preffered to put your code in the answer, instead of linking github.